# OpenCV could not find H264 Encoder

Tags: c++, opencv, encoding, ffmpeg, ros

Im trying to write a video to file using OpenCV on ROS to MP4 container using H264 encoding for web, but I keep getting:

```
Could not find encoder for codec id 28: Encoder not found
```

This is my code:

```
frame_writer.open(pathfile, CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4'),framerate, cv::Size(vpre[0].cols, vpre[0].rows),true);
```

I tried CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4'), CV_FOURCC('H','2','6','4') and it didn't work.

I reinstalled my ffmpeg from source, and when I run ffmpeg -codecs I get:

```
 DEV.LS h264   H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_vdpau ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb )
```

I don't understand why Im still getting the error.

Comment: afaik, you must compile openCV with h264 support.

Comment: @Micka this is ROS's OpenCV

Comment: did you try to choose -1 instead of a FOURCC code?

Comment: @Micka Yes, nothing appears...